# Writing a method to change label.visibility but why it is not hiding label

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am writing a code to change label visibility when condition is true. please advise why it is not changing. here is code:

```
bool Verify_data_Input(TextBox TB, Label ER)
{
    string input = TB.Text.Trim(),ot;
    bool mybool = false;
    txtoutput.Text = Convert.ToString(input.Length);
    if(input.Length >0)
    {
        ER.Visible = false;           
        mybool = true;
    }

    {
        ER.Visible = true;
        mybool = false;
    }

    return mybool;
}
```

Comment: Are you missing an `else` clause before setting `ER.Visible = true`?

Comment: There's also a syntax error/typo on the `string input` line.